# How best to convert old Dart code that triggers "The non-nullable variable must be assigned" error?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

Take the following non-null safe Dart code:

```
static String appBarShiftTitleString(int fromEpochSeconds) {
    String monthWord;  
    String dayWord;

    DateTime dt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(fromEpochSeconds * 1000);

    switch (dt.month) {
      case 1:
        monthWord = "Jan";
        break;
      case 2:
        monthWord = "Feb";
        break;
      case 3:
        monthWord = "Mar";
        break;
      case 4:
        monthWord = "Apr";
        break;
      case 5:
        monthWord = "May";
        break;
      case 6:
        monthWord = "Jun";
        break;
      case 7:
        monthWord = "Jul";
        break;
      case 8:
        monthWord = "Aug";
        break;
      case 9:
        monthWord = "Sep";
        break;
      case 10:
        monthWord = "Oct";
        break;
      case 11:
        monthWord = "Nov";
        break;
      case 12:
        monthWord = "Dec";
        break;
    }

    switch (dt.weekday) {
      case 1:
        dayWord = "Mon";
        break;
      case 2:
        dayWord = "Tue";
        break;
      case 3:
        dayWord = "Wed";
        break;
      case 4:
        dayWord = "Thu";
        break;
      case 5:
        dayWord = "Fri";
        break;
      case 6:
        dayWord = "Sat";
        break;
      case 7:
        dayWord = "Sun";
        break;
    }

    return dayWord + ' ' + monthWord + ' ' + dt.day.toString();
}
```

Android Studio is saying, "The non-nullable local variable 'dayWord' must be assigned before it can be used."

I understand the error and have discovered that I can simply modify the first two lines of the method like this:

```
String monthWord = "error!";
String dayWord = "error!";
```

This way, I satisfy the language rules, and it will be plainly obvious if we reach what ought to be an impossible situation of the variable not having been assigned.

This seems hacky though... so in these types of scenarios, what is the elegant and proper way to convert this code to null safety, and if there are multiple ways, then what are the pros and cons?

Comment: How did you get that code?  Did you use Dart migrate on a working project, or is this handcrafted?   Because if that's legacy code, it should run fine, unless you changed pubspec.yaml minsdk to 2.12 manually.

Comment: Its my own code from an old project.  Yes I effectively changed min to 2.12 by creating a new boilerplate flutter project using the latest Android Studio+Flutter+Dart versions.  Then I started cutting and pasting in from the old project.  This was on purpose -- I would rather encounter the errors and fix them and learn in the process than use the migration tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you have a few options:

### 1. Initialize the variable to some non-null sentinel value and `assert` later:

```dart
String monthWord = '';
// ...
switch (dt.month) {
  // ...
}
assert(monthWord.isNotEmpty);
```

This will cause debug builds to throw `AssertionError` at runtime if you neglect to handle a case for it in the `switch`.

### 2. Make the variable nullable and use the null assertion operator:

```dart
String? monthWord;
// ...
switch (dt.month) {
  // ...
}
monthWord!;

// Since `monthWord` is a local variable, it will now be promoted to a
// non-nullable `String` type.
```

This will throw a `TypeError` in all build types if you neglect to set the variable to a non-null value.

### 3. Make the variable `late`

Declaring variables as `late` states that you promise that the variables will be initialized before they are ever read.  The compiler will generate runtime checks that verify that the variable is initialized when you try to access it.  This will throw a `LateInitializationError` in all build types if you neglect to set the variable.

### 4. Add a `default` case that throws

If all of your `case`s set a local variable, adding a `default` case that throws allows the compiler to deduce that that variable must always be set if code after the `switch` statement is reached:

```dart
String monthWord; // No explicit initialization required!
// ...
switch (dt.month) {
  case 1:
    monthWord = "Jan";
    break;

  // ... etc. ...

  default:
    throw AssertionError('Unhandled case: ${dt.month}');  
}

// The compiler now can deduce that `monthWord` is guaranteed to be
// initialized.
```

(Note that you should *not* add a `default` case for this purpose if you're using a `switch` statement on an `enum` type.  For `enum`s, the compiler and analyzer can determine if your `case`s are exhaustive and will generate analysis warnings if you accidentally omit any cases.)

---

As for which approach to use, it's mostly a matter of preference.  They're all mostly equivalent in that they'll result in runtime errors.  I personally would choose #1 (`assert`) or #4 (`default` case) to avoid unnecessary checks in release builds.

In your particular example, I also would just use `DateTime.month` and `DateTime.day` as indices into `List`s of the month and day names respectively:

```dart
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
const days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];

assert(months.length == 12);
assert(days.length == 7);

var monthWord = months[dt.month - 1];
var dayWord = days [dt.day - 1];
```